# How do I align circular buttons in a circle in both landscape and portrait orientations on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, interface-builder

I would like to layout 5 buttons (that have a circular image) in a circular pattern (a kind of pentagon shape) in iOS.  Ultimately it will also work on iPad, but at the moment, I'm just trying to get it working on iPhone.

So far, I  have just tried putting them into a UIView and using constraints to lay them out via IB.  However, when I rotate the device to landscape the layout gets messed up.

Here is a picture of the kind of layout I mean in IB which should ideally adapt to fit both iPhone portrait and landscape.

[image: IB Layout]

If I fix the height and width, it's clearly too big for iPhone:

[image: Fixed Height and Width]

I guess I need to find a way to have it maintain it's aspect ratio as a square and aligned to the middle of the parent view.

If I constrain to the top layout guide with horizontal space and vertical space it just looks like this:

[image: Horizontal and Vertical Space]

I just can't seem to get my head around the right way to do this.

Any thoughts and pointers in the right direction greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your approach,

*Logic :* Use parametric equations to get points ( button centres ) along circumference of circle, Update constraints when screen rotates ( take outlets of constraints to modify ).

These formulae will give point ( x, y ) along circumference ( Centres of buttons / leading & top constraint of buttons )

```
 x = cx + r * cos(a)
 y = cy + r * sin(a)

 Where,
 r is the radius, ( in your case half of screen size )
 cx,cy the origin, ( in your case centre of view )
 and a the angle from 0..2PI radians or 0..360 degrees. ( Angle between two buttons 360/5 because there are 5 buttons )
```

I have used this formula in one of the control i have developed..

https://github.com/AdityaDeshmane/iOSCircularMenu

Check method `- (void)setButtonFrames` in following file

https://github.com/AdityaDeshmane/iOSCircularMenu/blob/master/iOSCircularMenu/CustomCircularMenuControlFiles/ADCircularMenuViewController.m